# pandas: how to register custom dataframe attributes?

Tags: python, pandas

Recent pandas version [provide a way to add](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html)  custom attributes to pandas dataframes. The example provided works.

My question is: How and when should this be registered? I have a large django project using dataframes in various places. How should I use this example so that custom attributes are available to all dataframe in the project?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, shouldn't you just register the namespace at some point before it is used, just like anything else?  As soon as you register it, it will be available to all dataframes in your project.  I think you  may be overthinking this.

Comment: Maybe in a module that is imported directly or indirectly by every module of your project that works with dataframes.